# Adding another column to my query with a distinct where clause

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to add another column to the first query with a separate where clause that isn't applied to the other columns?

```
select
  month(From_iso8601_timestamp(u.created)) as Month,
  count(distinct u.id) as Sign_Ups,
  count (distinct w.owner) as Sign_Ups_with_Want_Created,
  count(distinct g.owner) as Sign_Ups_with_Reel_Created
from
  prodjoinreel.users u
  left join prodjoinreel.goals g on g.owner = u.id
left join prodjoinreel.wants w on w.owner = u.id
where year(From_iso8601_timestamp(u.created)) = 2019
group by 1
order by 1
```

query with additional column I want to add (I only want the where g.status = 'done' applied to the Sign_ups_with_complete_reel column):

```
select
  count(distinct u.id) as New_Users
  , month(From_iso8601_timestamp(u.created)) as Month
from
  prodjoinreel.goals g
  right join prodjoinreel.users u on
    g.owner = u.id
where
  year(From_iso8601_timestamp(u.created)) = 2019
and g.status = 'done'
group by
  month(From_iso8601_timestamp(u.created)) as Month
order by
  month(From_iso8601_timestamp(u.created)) as Month asc
```

Thank you

Comment: `group by 2`? Why are you grouping by the integer 2? Also [Bad habits to kick : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal)

Comment: You can't group by ordinal position. You MUST use the expression of your column. So in this case it would be "group by month(From_iso8601_timestamp(u.created))" And I agree with @Larnu that you should not order by the ordinal position. It is problematic at best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you should move `g.status = 'done' from a where statement covering the whole query into a case statement inside the count aggregation.  I've done this below, and I also reworked your query a bit to avoid reduntancy in the month calculation:

```
select      New_Users = count(distinct u.id), 
            ap.Month,
            Sign_Ups_with_Want_Created = count(distinct w.owner),

            Sign_Ups_with_Reel_Created = 
                count(distinct 
                    case 
                    when g.status = 'done' then g.owner 
                    end
                )

from        prodjoinreel.goals g
right join  prodjoinreel.users u on g.owner = u.id
cross apply (select Month = From_iso8601_timestamp(u.created)) ap
where       year(From_iso8601_timestamp(u.created)) = 2019
group by    ap.Month
order by    ap.Month
```